# Using the properties of an object in a SQL query

Tags: php

I have a object and one of the properties is the database table that should be used in a query.

I want to pass the object to a function.

In the function I want to use property of the object which is the database table.

I have tried various statements but they all result in

`Notice: Undefined property: torrent::$get_table in C:\Users\...\functions.php on line 78
SQL query is SELECT COUNT(title) from '()' where title = 'The Zen of Recovery - Mel Ash'`

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(title) from '$objMyObject->get_table()'  where title = '$title'";
```

Am I doing it wrong or is it not possible?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please go look at (for example) PHP PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) it will help you 'build' queries

Answer (score 1):

PHP will try to evaluate $objMyObject->get_table as property instead of inteded method. That's why you get only parenthesis instead of intended value. You can use object properties or variables in double quotes but not a methods or functions.

To solve your problem you can approach it in two ways

```
$table = $objMyObject->get_table();
// notice {} will indicate that you intend to print variable value
// it's not mandatory but it's better practice
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(title) from '{$table}' where title = '$title'";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(title) from '" . $objMyObject->get_table() . "' where title = '$title'";
```